# SQL and PHP wall

Tags: php, sql

I need help with SQL and PHP. What I have in my SQL database is this:

### Posts

```
text         | by| post_id
Post 1 [...] | 2 | 1
Post 2 [...] | 3 | 2
Post 3 [...] | 6 | 3
Post 5 [...] | 8 | 4
Post 6 [...] | 9 | 5
```

### Following

```
to  | by
2   | 1
3   | 1
6   | 1
```

In the table above you can see that you are **user “1”** and what I want to do is to list the table “posts” and since I follow user 2, 3 and 6 as you can see in the table “following” I want to show them and if I add another line in following where I start to follow user 8. I also want to show his post. How to I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `by` IN (SELECT `to` FROM following WHERE `by` = user_id)
```

Comment: `$q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 'by' IN (SELECT 'to' FROM following WHERE 'by' = user_id)";
$r = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $text    = $row[0];
    echo"$text<br />";
 }` can't get it to work, in my code was **user_id** change to 1, whats wrong?

Comment: @Simon: `$q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 'by' IN (SELECT 'to' FROM following WHERE 'by' = '".$user_id."')";`